# Product of Sobolev spaces

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be measure spaces. I know that $L^2(X\times Y)$ is isomorphic to $L^2(X)\otimes L^2(Y)$.

Is there a similar property for Sobolev spaces? For istance, is true that $H^2([0,1]^2)\cong H^2([0,1])\otimes H^2([0,1])$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the tensor product $\otimes$ and the direct product $\times$?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo

Comment: Basically it is a matter of understanding the definitions. If the tensor product here is the complement of the algebraic tensor product so you only need these two results: (1) If $f,g\in H^2$ then $f(x)g(y)\in H^2([0,1]^2)$. (2) The polynomials are dense in $H^2([0,1]^2)$ with respect to the natural topology. I think you have both, so yes there is an equality.